# Powershell AD computer description append

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if some of powershell magicians here could advise on this please. 
I have script that diables computers from list and wanted to append description of that computer with date.

```
$TimeStamp = ((get-date).toshortdatestring())
$pclist = Get-Content C:\.Data\raports\test.txt
Foreach($pc in $Pclist)
{
Get-ADComputer -Identity "$pc" -Properties description |Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false -Description "$timestamp,"
}
```

I have tried to use

`-Description "$timestamp, $($_.description)"`

or

```
-Description "$timestamp, $($pc.description)"
```

but that only puts  the time stamp. 
Ideally I want to catch whatever was there before and update in frormat of date, old description

Many thansk for your adivce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `-Description` parameter of `Set-ADComputer` does not accept pipeline input.

```bsh
-Description <string>

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           Identity
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     true
```

You would need to complete the steps separately to obtain the computer object first.

```bsh
$TimeStamp = ((get-date).toshortdatestring())
$pclist = Get-Content C:\.Data\raports\test.txt
Foreach($pc in $Pclist)
{
    $Computer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $pc -Properties description
    $Computer | Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false -Description "$timestamp, $($Computer.Description)"
}
```

> Note: You should not need quotation marks around your `$pc` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipeline-bound parameter argument:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity "$pc" -Properties description |Set-ADComputer -Enabled:$false -Description { $timestamp,$_.description -join ',' }
```

Comment: Thank you for looking in to it.